# Trouble to send multiple attachment mail in laravel

Tags: laravel

Here is my controller code.

```
    $fileArray=$request->multiple_file;

    $data['name']="custom size mail";
    $message='ok message';

    Mail::send('emails.cutom_size_admin', $data, function($message) use ($fileArray)
    {
        $message->from('vv@gmail.com', 'Laravel');

        $message->to('vik@gmail.com')->cc('vv@gmail.com');

        for ($i=0; $i < count($fileArray); $i++) {
            $message->attach($fileArray[$i]);
        }
    });
```

and my CustomSizeMailToAdmin.php  mailable code is -

```
   public function build()
   {
     $email= $this->from('har@araa.com','Make Subject')->subject('Contact Mail')->view('emails.cutom_size_admin')->with('data', $this->data);
     foreach($attachments as $filePath){
        $email->attach($filePath);
    }
    return $email;
    }
```

And my form html is-

```
    <input type="file" multiple name="multiple_file[]" id="multiple_file">
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I believe you don't need to duplicate code twice (in controller).

Comment: Did you include `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your opening form tag?

Comment: @AndrewSavetchuk , i says "Undefined variable: fileArray" . but when i dump the fileArray above of data['name'] then it shows all files array

Comment: @symlink, yes sir i've included  enctype='multipart/form-data'   .

Answer (score 0):

I did it.
Now here is my controller code-

```
$fileArray=$request->multiple_file;
for ($i=0; $i < count($fileArray); $i++) {
     $fileext = $fileArray[$i]->getClientOriginalExtension();
     $data['filepath'][$i]['fileimg'] = now()->format('dmyHis') .mt_rand(1000000, 9999999). '.' . $fileext;
     $destinationPath = 'public/assets/images/customsize/';
     $data['filepath'][$i]['filemove'] = $fileArray[$i]->move($destinationPath, 
     $data['filepath'][$i]['fileimg']);
 }
 if(isset($toEmail) && $toEmail!=''){
      Mail::to('makefoam@gmail.com')->send(new CustomSizeMailToAdmin($data));
 }
```

and my CustomSizeMailToAdmin.php mailable code is -

```
public function build()
{
     $email= $this->from('har@araa.com','Make Subject')->subject('Contact Mail')->view('emails.cutom_size_admin')->with('data', $this->data);
     foreach($this->data['filepath'] as $filePath){
        $email->attach('https://makemyfoam.com/'.$filePath['filemove']);
    }
    return $email;
}
```